# Checking if an HTML Element is in the Viewport

Tags: javascript, applescript

My Applescript that uses JavaScript inside it attempts to return true if an element is in the viewport.

So far, it's not working and returning “missing value” even though “var ele” is properly targetted and the browser is allowing JavaScript from Apple Events.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

```
tell application "Brave Browser" to tell active tab of front window
    execute JavaScript "

var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('tBJ dyH iFc SMy yTZ erh DrD IZT mWe')[0];

function isVisible (ele) {
  const { top, bottom } = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
  const vHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  return (
    (top > 0 || bottom > 0) &&
    top < vHeight
  );
}
"

end tell
```

Comment: Currently you are not invoking the `isVisible` function anywhere in your JS, so you need to either call it after the actual function definition i.e. `isVisible(ele);`, or make it an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) instead. Also return just the following: `return (top > 0 || bottom > 0) && top < vHeight;` - it's not necessary to contain that in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not actually running the function `isVisible`.

You can verify that Brave is returning values from `execute javascript` by using a simpler script:

```
tell application "Brave Browser"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "1"
    end tell
end tell
```

Or you can follow the logic in the JavaScript portion of the script by running it directly in a test page in the browser; if you do the latter, you’ll see that you

1. assign the element to the `var ele`.
2. create the function `isVisible` that takes one argument.
3. but never actually call the function `isVisible`.

You can fix this by either calling the function or removing the function, depending on your needs.

Call the function; note that I’ve replaced getElementsByClassName with getElementsByTagName to be able to more easily test it on arbitrary web pages:

```
tell application "Brave Browser"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "
var firstParagraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
isVisible(firstParagraph)

function isVisible (elementToCheck) {
  const { top, bottom } = elementToCheck.getBoundingClientRect();
  const vHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  return (
    (top > 0 || bottom > 0) &&
    top < vHeight
  );
}
"
    end tell
end tell
```

Or, for example, removing the function:

```
tell application "Brave Browser"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "
var firstParagraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var firstParagraphRect = firstParagraph.getBoundingClientRect();
var top = firstParagraphRect.top
var vHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
(firstParagraphRect.top > 0 || firstParagraphRect.bottom > 0) && firstParagraphRect.top < vHeight

    "
    end tell
end tell
```

In each case you can replace tag name “p” with a tag that is not visible, such as “title” to see that it also returns false correctly.